# Ignoring multiple return values in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

In Racket, it's possible to return multiple values from a function by doing e.g.

```
(define (foo)
  (values 1 2 3))
```

Then we can bind them by doing

```
(define-values (one two three) (foo))
```

Now `one` is bound to `1`, `two` to `2`, and `three` to `3`.

I have a function that returns multiple values, but I'm interested only in some of them. Is there a way of extracting the "interesting" return values, while "ignoring" (i.e. not binding) the rest, a la `_` pattern in Haskell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `match-let-values` or `match-define-values` for this (depending on whether you want lexical or top-level variables):

```
> (match-let-values (((_ _ a _) (values 1 2 3 4)))
    a)
; => 3

> (match-define-values (_ a _ _) (values 1 2 3 4))
> a
; => 2
```

Comment: Is there any reason why define-values is hanging around then? It seems to be a proper subset of match-define-variables

Comment: @jozefg Well `define-values` is basically a low-level primitive, too. If you run any code through the macro expander with the option to show _everything_, you'll see `define-values` all over the place. After all, `define` is the special case of `define-values` where there's only one value, so `define` gets expanded into `define-values`. EDIT: Conceptually I suppose `define-values` could expand into `match-define-values`, but `match` is a more-recent and "higher level" addition to the language. I guess that question is above my pay grade. :)

Comment: As Greg writes, `define-values` is a primitive. That is, it is one of the forms that can appear in "fully expanded syntax". The JIT compiler therefore knows how to compile `define-values`. The form `match-define-values` on the other expand into a bunch of much simpler syntax. This is of course just an implementation detail - one could hide `define-values` and then export `match-define-values` as `define-values`. In other systems `define-values` might be a macro that expands to `call-with-values`. See for example: http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-macros#multidefine

Comment: `match-define-values` is probably implemented as a define-syntax/syntax-rules that translate the form to `call-with-values` to reduce the values and `define-values` to define them.