# How to consume only the first returned value in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, multiple-value, r7rs

Given a Scheme function returning multiple values, for example:

```
(exact-integer-sqrt 5) ⇒ 2 1
```

How can I use only the first returned value, ignoring the other ones?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignoring multiple return values in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200362/ignoring-multiple-return-values-in-racket)

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm looking for a Scheme answer. I am not using Racket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`call-with-values`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._call-with-values%29%29) inside macro:

```
(define-syntax first-val
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((first-val fn)
     (car (call-with-values (lambda () fn) list)))))

(first-val (values 1 2 3 4))
(first-val (exact-integer-sqrt 5))
```

There are also [`define-values`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._define-values%29%29) and [`let-values`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._let-values%29%29), if you know number of returned values.

```
(define-values (x y) (exact-integer-sqrt 5)) ;global

(let-values ([(x y z) (values 1 2 3)]) ;local
    x)
```

Source: [R7RS report](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`let-values`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._let-values%29%29):

```
(let-values (((root rem) (exact-integer-sqrt 5)))
  root)
```

The above will extract both results in separate variables, and you can choose which one you need.